# table view cell deleting not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I've used the sdk standard code for deleting however it crashes once I press the delete button.
I am using this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableFavoritesData arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }
}
```

I tried with both NSMutableArray instead of tableFavoritesData however nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, basically what you want to do is:

1. Delete the row from the data source (array).
2. Tell the table view that you have deleted a row from the data source.

Correct code should probably look like that:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 [tableFavoritesData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }
```

EDIT: I didn't notice another error.

You need to specify the type of animation, not just pass YES or NO. For example: UITableViewRowAnimationFade. Check out possible UITableViewRowAnimation values [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewRowAnimation).

EDIT 2: For the comment below (comment formatting suck):
Check out [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-1265) in the docs, especially addObserver:selector:name:object: and postNotificationName:object: methods.

In your other view controller (probably viewDidLoad method):

```
[[NSNotificationServer defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deletedRow:) name:@"RowDeleted" object:nil];

-(void) deletedRow:(NSNotification*) notification
{
  NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
  NSIndexPath indexPath = [userInfo objectForKey:@"IndexPath"];
 // your code here
}
```

and while deleting the row:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
...
[[NSNotificationServer defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RowDeleted" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:indexPath forKey:@"IndexPath"]];
     }
```

Just remember that you need to remove observer from notification center when you dealloc the other UIViewController:

```
[[NSNotificationServer defaultCenter] removeObserver: self];
```

Hope I didn't make much errors, I don't have access to XCode atm.

Comment: great thanks a lot.
(a sidenote to my question i have an array of data that is copied from another controller to the one that has a table. is there any way to remove an object from that array without having to recopy the entire array and nsuserdefault it again if it is removed?)

Comment: I''ve added some sample code to the answer, couldn't edit my comment as it was edited already. Generally you want to register your other ViewController as an observer, and post a notification to it while deleting the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you looked at the console, it will most probably tell you that your model (your data structure) doesn't match what the table expects. I.e. your delegate method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

must return one less than before.

Also, `[tableFavoritesData arrayWithObject:indexPath]` looks very strange and is probably not what's expected. Maybe you want `[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]` here. And remove the data from your model first.